# Is there a better way to get accurate count?

Tags: python, object-detection, image-segmentation, opencv, watershed

i'm working on this project to get accurate number of fishes in images. However, i've used pixellib but couldn't get accurate result. Is there any package that could just count objects in an image and give accurate result?

This is a test image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUa79.jpg

This is the output of the test image.

[image]

Or will watershed algorithm be better because the object recognition is not important than the number of fishes in the image ?

Comment: so... train your instance segmentation DNN on more/better data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to spend any resource on segmentation if the actual goal is just to count your objects. Object detection might be enough.

It is important to choose because you definitely need to train a custom model because of the specific form, partially visible objects, overlapping, etc.

I've just tried to segment your example:

[image]

another part:

[image]

BTW, it is better to improve overall input quality. Anyway, segmented results might be used to "measure" shapes, so in a way joined shapes can be properly "interpreted".

You can prepare a specific training set, so your model will recognize all corner cases in a proper way, but it might take some time.

[image]

Object detection will not require so many efforts:

[image]

Long story short: improve your input (if possible) and try to use any suitable [tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=rcnn%20object%20detection%20tutorial)

**Update**

Bounding box (detection) vs accurate shape (segmentation) discussion is quite useless, because the goal is to get an accurate count, so let's address another issue:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even a super advanced model/approach will fail with the example provide. I'd suggest to start with any possible/reasonable input improvement.

Comment: Using object detection prove to be effective only on clearer images. However, for some images, this method won't give accurate result. Getting object count is the goal.

Comment: @alic, let's make sure we do understand everything in the same way: "Object detection ... deals with detecting instances of semantic objects of a certain class", "Image segmentation is the process of partitioning a digital image into multiple segments", according to your statement it is easier to segment a poor quality image...

Object detection is actually about count. The reason I mentioned that is because object detection training set will be simpler. Up to you to choose the approach. Are you going to do anything special with the detailed geometry (in case of segmentation)?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. object detection with bounding boxes *will* have trouble. take those two things on the bottom right. they'd have severely overlapping bounding boxes. NMS will discard one or merge both. -- instance segmentation has the most promise to solve the problem. -- the issue in the question is insufficiently trained instance segmentation. the presented results don't see some objects, and merge some objects.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, are you saying accurate segmentation solves overlapping issue? From the training set preparation and model tuning perspective it is easier to deal with complex scenes, for example: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37084898/45520936-611ee100-b7d9-11e8-816b-38a4ff6cb3f4.gif or https://bitmovin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Object_detection_Blog_Image_Q3_19.jpg

The issue in the question is accurate count. Segmentation is the approach taken, which is too complex for the problem stated.

Comment: The goal of this is to get accurate count. Either using instance segmentation or any other library. What i want to know is that what is the best approach to solve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: @alic, is there any way to improve input?

Comment: @Renat the only way is to have access to training images. Do you want me to share that ?

Comment: @alic, I mean is there any way to enhance the way you get those training images? With the current example you won't be able to get accurate number even if best possible model is available (complex groups, corners).